# Type of people with 'aparadha' vasana

Tags: meaning, tripura-rahasyam

While discussing Vasanas, Dattatreya tells Parashurama about aparadha Vasana and the *categories of people* with the aparadha Vasna. Among the several categories of people having aparadha Vasana, I have difficulty understanding a particular category.

The following is the Sanskrit verse saying about that particular category

> **निदिध्यासन न्तसाधनेन ज्ञात्वापि नैतत्परं त्वमिति तृतीयः**
>
> [[16, 19, Ganana Kanda, Tripura Rahasyam]](https://archive.org/details/TripuraRahasyamJnanaKhandaGopinathKaviraj/page/n396/mode/1up?view=theater)

Although the [English translation](https://archive.org/details/TripuraRahasyaEnglishTranslation/page/n202/mode/2up?view=theater) of this particular verse is available, it does not seem to be the exact translation preserving the semantics

> if one claims to know it, it is an illusion of the mind;

So I want to know the exact meaning of the verse in that particular context. What is the exact meaning of the verse by Dattatreya about this particular category of people with aparadha Vasana?

Comment: निदिध्यासन अन्त साधनेन ज्ञातु अपि न एतत् परं त्वं इति तृतीयः

Comment: @YOuwillnotknow What is the meaning of that?